# Execute php file without include: shell_exec() has been disabled

Tags: php, shell, exec, shared-hosting, shell-exec

I need to make use of the PHP function `shell_exec()`. Unfortunately I'm using shared hosting and `shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons`.

With the cron job `php -q /home/user_name/exec_test.php >/dev/null 2>&1` I found out, `shell_exec()` is only disabled in `/home/user_name/public_html/` but not in `/home/user_name/`, which I can access via cron job.

Of course, I cannot access the directory `/home/user_name/` via browser. (I would prefer not to use cron job.)

My idea was to `include` (`include "/home/user_name/exec_test.php";`) my exec file from a php script in the browser accessible direction. Unfortunately this gives me the same error: `shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons`

Is there a way I can reach what I want? Is there a way to execute `/home/user_name/exec_test.php` without include it in `/home/user_name/public_html/` directory?

Comment: I think its better to contact your hosting provider about this.

Comment: It would be better to avoid using `shell_exec` after all. If you can define cronjobs, you could also use a bash script to solve your problem

Comment: @Jan-WillemdeBoer I don't think then will break the security for me.

Comment: @NicoHaase I can create cron jobs via cPanel on my shared hosting. My goal (why I want to use `shell_exec `) is to execute a PHP script without waiting for it until it's ready executed. Can I do that with a bash script? I'm not familiar with bash scripts.